# UITableView blurred background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController (static table)  to which I add a background image with (in viewDidLoad):

`tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "login_bg.jpg"))`

How do I add the blurred effect to that background image?

**I tried with:** (in viewDidLoad)

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.tableView.backgroundView = blurEffectView
```

It works but it does not catch the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the blur effect view as a subview instead of setting it as the background view.

```
    self.tableView.backgroundView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Step 1 :

Set the background image.

```
 tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img"))
```

Step 2:

Create blur effect view and add it as subview.

```
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        self.tableView.backgroundView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Here is how it looks.[image]